# Onsen UI React Native Uncaught Error code 500

Tags: react-native, onsen-ui

I made a new react native app by running the following code:

```
create-react-native-app test
cd test
npm install react-onsenui --save
npm start
```

After running those, the server starts but when I try to run the app, it gives me this error in Expo app:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The library you are trying to use is a web ui library. Since react-native doesn't have html dom elements this library won't work with it unless you somehow manage to convert it.